# Reading from an object while it’s being updated

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I’m writing an api that reads and writes to DynamoDB. I have one concern, let’s say I have a table and an item in that table that looks like:

’’’
{
“id”: 123,
“status”: “unapproved”,
“info”: “some text”
}
’’’

One user is updating the status, and another is trying to read it simultaneously, will one or both tasks fail? And what if one is updating the status and the other is requesting the info?

does DynamoDB handles such cases or do I need to come up with a way to “lock” this item and have all other tasks wait until writing to it is done?

The flow is;
Front end-> api gateway-> lambda api
The same lambda does both tasks and gets Triggered 2 times separately

Comment: I think yes, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870403/dynamodb-concurrent-write)

Comment: Aside from the mechanics of updating the database, I would encourage you to consider what you want the user experience to be.  If I'm viewing a field in table, and another user updates the underlying data, what happens?  Do I find out what I was viewing was stale iff I edit and save the same field?  Do I get some sort of notification if someone else edits the data that backs the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you can use eventual consistency or strong consistency:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

By default, the AWS SDK uses eventual consistency. You have to set the ConsistentRead parameter to use strong consistency.

Caveats:

- strong consistency is a little bit slower (it has to wait for any conflicting operations to make sure that the result that is returned is absolutely, 100%, the accurate value at the time of the request)
- strongly consistent reads are also more expensive as they consume more throughput

In most cases, you should design your application to accept reads that are not 100% accurate after write, as this should only take a few microseconds/milliseconds for your data to be eventually consistent. For instance, you can just optimistically return the new Item when you write it ("I'm confident that this is what the database will look like in a few milliseconds") and account for this maybe wrong/inaccurate/outdated data in your application, so that you don't have to read it from the database again) (also, it's expensive and slow to do that, for no good reason, so just don't). But when you really, really, really need to make sure that you are reading the accurate, updated data, use strong consistency. There is a good reason it's not the default though.

> One user is updating the status, and another is trying to read it simultaneously, will one or both tasks fail?

No, the read operation simply *may or may not* return outdated data.

> And what if one is updating the status and the other is requesting the
> info?

Read might have the new or the old value, depending on how precisely simultaneous it was. But basically, just the time it takes for the networking latency between the user's machine and the database is usually enough for eventual/strong consistency to not really matter. If your application is sensitive to race conditions or must 100% ensure that the read data is the same as the write data 1 microsecond after it was written, use strong consistency.